# how to get the value of type object in el-transfer Element UI?

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I fill an array of objects, which the array passed as data to the transfer.

```
[
 {
  key:0,
  name: "Texto",
  options: [],
  readableName: "Named Insured",
  type: "text"
 }
]
```

In this way I have configured `<el-transfer>`

```
<el-transfer
   v-model="value"
   :data="data"
  :props="{
      key: 'key',
      label: 'readableName'

   }"
   @change="handleChange"
>
 <el-button class="transfer-footer" slot="right-footer" size="small" 
  @click="confirmFields(value)">Confirm</el-button>
</el-transfer>
```

and when obtaining 'value' in the method

```
confirmFields(fields){
            console.log(fields);
 },
```

I get an array with the keys, but I need to get an array of objects, where each object is an item from the list. In other words, return it to me in this way:

```
[
     {
      key:0,
      name: "Texto",
      options: [],
      readableName: "Named Insured",
      type: "text"
     }
]
```